# Difference between polypeptides and polyamides

Tags: polymers

I can't seem to find a very good explanation of the difference between polypeptides and polyamides. So far, I know that polypeptides are a type of polyamides, but that is about it. My guess is that the term polyamides refers both to the polymers made from amino acids and those made from diamines and dicarboxylic acids, but polypeptides are only those made of amino acids, but this is just a guess...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess Polypeptides are naturally occurring for eg. Polymers of Amino acids whereas Polyamides are synthesize by condensation process of polymerization for eg. Nylon 6 and nylon 6.6.
Polypeptides are a type of Polyamides. It's only guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is correct. Polyamides are polymers where the repeating units are linked by amide bonds. Polypeptides are a specific type of polyamide where the repeating units are amino acids.

Answer (score 1):

Peptides (or polypeptides) are polymers of amino acids; usually created by cell enzymes.

Polyamides usually have a carbon chain between the amides, such as nylon 6 or nylon 66. Peptides could be classified as polyamides, but are not usually included since they have their own group.

Comment: Technically, polypeptides are a subset of polyamides.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a "mer" unit is polymer chemistry and polyamides (e.g. kevlar) are common. They are also liquid crystals. A polyamide is anything that has repeating amide bonds. Any amide (diamide to be precise) can be made into a polyer.

[image: difference between polyamide and polypeptide]

From Organic-ese.com